# Detecting video resolution changes

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

With some codecs and containers, it's possible for a video to change resolution mid-stream.  This is particularly common with RTC-style video streams where resolution can scale up/down based on available bandwidth.  In other cases, the recording device might be rotated and the video may flip from portrait to landscape or vice versa.

When playing these videos on a web page (simple `<video>` tag), how can I detect when this change in size occurs with JavaScript?

The best I can think of is verifying the size of the video every frame, but there is quite a bit of overhead to this method.  If there were a way to have a callback fired when the video changed sizes, or an event triggered, that'd be best.

Example video that resizes, severely:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8722238

Comment: `onresize` or `onratechange` any help?

Comment: does `onresize` not work for you as @dandavis suggested?

Comment: Do you have an example of a video that does this to test with? :)

Comment: @GregHornby I'll make one today.  My apologies for not having that already.

Comment: I'm not sure there are really video like you describe, where the resolution changes mid-track, but i anxiously await digging into one if you can share it.

Comment: @Brad correct me if I'm wrong: what you want is to check whether the device changed orientation, like from portrait to landscape and resize it accordingly? By the way, nice challenge =)

Comment: @n0m4d That's one reason a video can change resolution, but not the only one.  Other times include video received via WebRTC where there is less bandwidth so the resolution is reduced.  It's also possible for a normal video file to have resolution changes.  (Sometimes some scenes are shot wider than others, for example.)

Comment: @dandavis Yes, these videos definitely exist.  Here's an example:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8722238  Play it in VLC (not full screen or maxmized, with VLC set to resize when the video size changes) and watch VLC resize.

Comment: @Brad _"with VLC set to resize when the video size changes"_ Which preference at vlc did you use to set this affect at playback?

Comment: @guest271314 It's the default option, but Tools -> Preferences.  In simple mode in the Interface section, "Resize interface to video size"

Comment: @Brad Have not used `vlc` in some time. Played video several occasions without being aware that "Resize interface to video size" was set. Tried at both full window and minimized window. Could not detect any visual changes to `vlc` window? What is expected effect?

Comment: @guest271314 Try updating VLC.  You might have an old version.  Don't maximize the window, just leave it as-is, and when you play the video, it will start to resize VLC.

Comment: @Brad Updated to version 2.0.8. Do you mean the initial re-size of the window?

Comment: @guest271314 No, there will be an initial re-size, and then as the video plays, the video will resize repeatedly.  I'm on 2.2.1, but I don't know when this was added to the decoder.  My guess is a long time ago, but not sure.

Comment: @Brad Do you mean the actual video re-sizes, or the application window re-sizes?

Comment: @guest271314 The actual video resizes, which resizes the application window with it.

Comment: @Brad _"The actual video resizes, which resizes the application window with it."_ The described effect was not rendered, here; will try to view at a different newer version of `vlc`. Is this what you are trying to achieve? That is, resize a window or container when video resolution changes, in browser?

Comment: @guest271314 Usually in-browser, the browser will resize the video element, assuming it has no styling and sizing set.  I'm trying to detect when this occurs for a few reasons.  One of which is that I'm copying the video to a couple canvas elements and I need the dimensions to calculate a bunch of drawing parameters.  I've found that re-checking height/width every frame can be inefficient.  It might be the only way to do this, which is fine, but I'm trying to see if there's a prescribed way with an event or something.

Comment: @Brad _"I've found that re-checking height/width every frame can be inefficient"_ What do you mean by inefficient? What would be alternative? Pipe input stream to both video and canvas instead of copy from one to the other?

Comment: @guest271314 The alternative would be that the underlying player would fire an event, allowing the browser to fire a JavaScript event, which I could catch and then get the new height/width only when it changes.  This may not exist today... it should, but it might not.  I'm asking if it does, or if something similar exists.  Or if it doesn't exist, if someone could prove that, I'd award a bounty to that answer as well.

Comment: @Brad _"only when it changes"_ The logic would require checking constantly to determine if a change has occurred, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 The codec knows when the video size changes.  It has to decode the video to raw pixels after all.  What I'm saying is that the underlying codec is already doing the work, and it's already notifying the browser of the size change since the browser changes the element size.  If I check the video size every frame in JavaScript, not only is it inefficient, but there's also no guarantee that my frames (done with requestAnimationFrame) will have the same timing as the video's frames.  I want the browser to tell my code when the video changes size, rather than asking it repeatedly.

Comment: @Brad Could you stream to `canvas` first, then use same value from within `requestAnimationFrame` to set `video` `src`? See https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#html-canvas-element-media-capture-extensions

Comment: @guest271314 I'm already using CanvasCaptureStream and what not, but like I said, requestAnimationFrame doesn't guarantee genlock with video.

Comment: @Brad Not certain why you cannot use single function to stream to both `canvas` and `video`? Are you trying to achieve exact duplication as to rendering time and dimensions at both elements?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, but that's unrelated to my current problem.  Currently, I'm just looking for an event that fires when the video resizes, or proof that such an event doesn't exist.

Comment: @Brad _" I'm just looking for an event that fires when the video resizes, or proof that such an event doesn't exist. "_ No description matches where video re-sizing fires event at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: i can find no evidence that your sample video changes resolution, using MPC or `<video>` tags. Again, i'd like to believe you, but nothing i've ever seen says what you say is common or even possible... Do keep in mind that the video image is separate from the video encoding, and that internal scaling may occur, but video players won't be privy to such happenings.

Comment: @Brad  _"Yes, these videos definitely exist. Here's an example:"_ Cannot reproduce changes to `.videoWidth`, `.videoHeight` properties at sample video https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8722238. `.videoWidth`, `.videoHeight` were logged as `1920`, `1080` respectively; using both `timeupdate` event, and `setInterval` with `duration` set to `10`, where same values, that is, `1920`, `1080` were logged 3032 times.

Comment: @Brad http://plnkr.co/edit/fW3qfaeKg8TuEtiw9uOt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a `resize` event which fires when the video resolution changes.

#### HTML

```
<p data-content="resolution"></p>
<video src="https://bug1250345.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8722238"></video>
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  document.querySelector('[data-content="resolution"]').textContent = [
    e.target.videoWidth,
    e.target.videoHeight
  ].join('x');
});
```

(JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qz61o2xt/)

References:

- [HTML Living Standard Media Events - resize](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-resize)
- [Chromium Bug: Add a 'resize' event to  elements for when the video data changes dimensions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328140)
- [Chromium Bug: Fire 'resize' event on initial metadata load, too.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329392)

Comment: Weird it's not on MDN yet, FF seems to support it, Safari too, and it seems it's in the specs since at least 3 years... But the ordering of DOM events in MDN makes me reluctant to make a page by myself (there is already a [/Web/Events/resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize), so maybe they should gather all Media Events inside a sub-directory, but that would be a lot of work... Anyway, [someone asked for this 3 years ago.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209324)

Answer (score 2):

look if this helps I'm not sure.

Link - https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loadedmetadata` event to define global variables or utilize `Element.dataset` to reflect initial `.videoWidth`, `.videoHeight` properties of `<video>` element; at `timeupdate` event of `<video>` initially stored and current event `.videoWidth`, `.videoHeight` values, if one of the properties changed call function

```
window.onload = function() {
  function handleResolutionChange(event) {
    // do stuff if `.videoWidth` or `.videoHeight` changed from initial value
  }
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(event) {
    event.target.dataset.width = event.target.videoWidth; 
    event.target.dataset.height = event.target.videoHeight;
  })
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event) {
    if (+event.target.dataset.width !== event.target.videoWidth
        && +event.target.dataset.height !== event.target.videoHeight) {
          // call `handleResolutionChange` one or more times
          // if `event.target` `.videoWidth` or `.videoHeight` changed
          handleResolutionChange.call(event.target, event)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this really isn't much different than polling the video height/width every frame.  Is there no event I can listen to?

Comment: @Brad _"but this really isn't much different than polling the video height/width every frame."_ How would you be able to be aware of the change of a property at a frame without checking nearly every frame?  _"Is there no event I can listen to?"_ Not certain what you mean? You could probably create a custom function which checks `.videoWidth`, `.videoHeight` recursively; or you can listen at the `timeupdate` event of the `<video>`  element,  which should return same result.

Comment: Having one timeupdate event isn't that performance intensive at all, even on mobile

Comment: @guest271314 I'm hoping for an event where the underlying player notifies me immediately as the video changes resolution.

Comment: @GregHornby `timeupdate` isn't appropriate in my use case.  I need to catch the video resize on the frame in which it occurs.  Therefore, I have to use `requestAnimationFrame` and check the video size.  I suppose the performance of this is adequate and is what I'll do if there is no other solution... but I asked the question to try to find out if there was a better way.  There may very well not be a better way, but I'm hoping there is and hoping someone on Stack Overflow knows about it, hence the question and bounty.

Comment: this code doesn't fire any events on the test video, so one of the two is wrong..

Comment: @dandavis You are correct.  `.videoWidth`, `.videoHeight` of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8722238 appears to be set at  `1920`, `1080` respectively, using approach at Answer and `setInterval`  http://plnkr.co/edit/fW3qfaeKg8TuEtiw9uOt

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up re-checking `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` every frame.  No ideal, but it's what I have to do for now.