# How to identify incoming stream is landscape or portrait on HLS

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, opentok, hls.js

I am streaming a live broadcast on the web for that purpose I am using opentok as a webRTC and publishing the stream using an android app and showing that stream on the web by using HLS. But I have a different design on the web for landscape and portrait streams. So I want to identify the incoming stream on the web is landscape or portrait. So, I can change the design on the web according to that and ideally also want to listen for stream dimensions on the web. So if the dimension of the stream from the android app is changed I can also update the design on the web also.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting video resolution changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438741/detecting-video-resolution-changes)

Answer (score 2):

To get a video's resolution use...

```
let W=V.videoWidth;

let H=V.videoHeight;
```

And then use simple logic like this...

```
if(W>=H){

 // landscape
    
} else {

 // portrait

}
```

**NB:** Not to be confused with *V.width* and *V.height* which refer to the player's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the video height and width.

```
if width >= height: landscape layout
elif width < height: portrait layout
```

Comment: Video width and height is always the same in landscape and portrait